# Edit a shape with Visio 2010?

Tags: editing, microsoft-visio-2010, shapes

In previous Visio version I was able to "open" shapes which opened up a new drawing containing only the shape. In this mode you could edit/change/modify (e.g. remove certain parts) shapes that come with Visio. The command for opening a shape was the last entry in the edit menu called "[shape name] open...".

In Visio 2010 with it's new ribbon menu band I am not able to find something similar. Where is this function hidden?

Update: I found out that this feature is sill included in Visio 2010 - however I am still looking for the GUI element. At the moment I use the following work-around:

1. Enable the "development tab"
2. Select the shape to be edited
3. Open the "Shape name" dialog and memorize the Name
4. Replace in the Macro printed at the end of this question "Sheet.53" with the memorized shape name
5. Start the macro

Macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.Item("Sheet.53")
    s.OpenDrawWindow.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome help, thanks!

I improved the code a bit, which means you don't have to hard code the shape name.

Instead use this macro:

```
Sub EditObject()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
    s.OpenDrawWindow.Activate
End Sub
```

Save this Macro just as you have.  Go into the "Behavior" (on the Developer tab) of the shape you want to edit, and change the Double-Click (tab 2) to "Run Macro", and select your macro.

Now, double clicking on the shape should bring up the edit window.

Answer (score 1):

In Visio 2010 the menu option to "Open" a shape appears at the bottom of the Group menu.  Right-click the shape, then choose "Group" and then choose "Open [shape name]".  For other shape editing features see http://youtu.be/hCHsfb06o9g